# Q: Batch documents using DocuSign REST API? Not bulk envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have a client that would like to send out batches of contracts for signatures (hundreds at a time).  They would also like to use email for the recipients to log into docusign and sign.  Only problem is that many of the recipients on these docs are the same couple of people, and thus, would end up with a flooded inbox after every contract batch.

Does DocuSign have a different email correspondence option?  Maybe one that would send out 1 email if recipients have documents they need to take action on?  This would be something that we need to control when creating and sending the envelopes because many of these users would be logging in for the first time when they sign their first document, and probably wouldn't know how to configure their settings appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever an envelope is sent, the recipient will receive an email notification from Docusign. Sender will not be able to disable these notifications to the recipient.

Recipients can control the notifications they receive using the [Manage Notifications](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-manage-notifications) page